# Android SDK 4.2 won't generate activity class

Tags: android, class

when i create a Android Application Projet and follow the steps, i check the box create activity as blank activity and when i finished i can't found the class in src, is this normal ?
[image]

Comment: This is not normal, plz add the steps your using.

Comment: i'm using Eclipse Indigo / android SDK 4.1.2 and here are the steps : File > Android Application Projet > Minimum Required SDK API 10 > target SDK AP 21> Compile with API 16 > create activity (checked)> create activity (cheched) as Blank Activity and finish.

Comment: thank you Piyush Kukadiya "Empty activity" was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
go to Help>(select)>Install New Software..>And paste this Url: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`And update the Developer Tools. It works for me

Comment: problem solved : when i create new Android Application Project at the final step i must choose "Empty Activity" instead of "Blank Activity".